# Printing data automatic from register in Windbg

Tags: windows, gdb, kernel, windbg

I wanted to know how to print data automatic when the debugger hits breakpoint,
for example:
`"dq $rax L24"`  -> I want this command will be executed automatically when it hits specific breakpoint.

Thanks :)

Comment: You can simply add the command to execute when your breakpoint hits by adding it when setting your breakpoint - `bp xxx "dq $rax L24;g"`.

Comment: use gc go from conditional instead of g bp addr statement ;gc

Comment: @blabb - Never quit understood the difference. Rereading the help on it, my current understanding is that it does not matter for op's use case, does it? (I assume op's use case is to set the breakpoint and keep the program running)

Comment: may be it doesn't matter for op since he probably hits it with g and would want to resume with g  but assume if you were stepping and this bp was hit during the step. with g you wont get control to your next step ( step over a call maybe and this is call within your stepped over call) as it would resume free and there is no internal breakpoint set by windbg on your next step

Comment: added a sample scenerio @LievenKeersmaekers take a look

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers -> Thanks, that "bp xxx "dq $rax L24;g" works. Do you know how do i assign the register value into variable and use it later ?

Answer (score 1):

use bp  "dq @rax l24;gc" syntax
this will break print and resume automatically

To Address comment by @Lieven

gc resumes the execution as is
with gc if you were **stepping in** the execution post hit would be **step in**
or if you were **stepping over** the execution status post hit would be **step over**
or if you were **using g continue freely** execution post hit would be g **or execute freely**

lets test it with a simple contrived example code

```
int c (int c) {
    int z =23;
    return c+z;
}
int b (int b) {
    int y=7;
    return c( y+b);
}
int a(int a){
    int x=3;
    return b( x+a );
}
int main (void)
{
    int g =0;
    for (int i =0 ;i< 10; i++){
        g = g+a(i);
    }
    return g;
}
```

1. you set a breakpoint like  like **bp foo!b "r rax;g"**
2. you were stepping over the function foo!a in main()
3. the for loop counter i was at  1
4. the execution wont return control to your loop and you cant step  over foo!a the next nine times until i becomes 10
   post breakpoint resumption the program will simply run the complete loop and exit

see below the conditional has g

explanation of possibly gibberish looking command

```
**cdb -c "bp foo!b \"r rcx;g\";g main;pc;p" foo.exe |awk "/Reading/,/quit/"**
```

1. cdb takes -c as as argument and passes the quoted string that
   follows as command to be executed post system breakpoint
2. **"bp foo!b "r rcx;g";g main;pc;p"**  is the quoted string to be passed as initial command
3. "bp foo!b "r rcx;g" is the conditional with escaped quotes inside
4. g main runs the program upto main();
5. pc steps over up to the next call (foo!a) in this case
6. p steps over the call (foo!a)

executed

```
cdb -c "bp foo!b \"r rcx;g\";g main;pc;p" foo.exe |awk "/Reading/,/quit/"  
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'bp foo!b "r rcx;g";g main;pc;p'  
rcx=0000000000000003  
rcx=0000000000000004  
rcx=0000000000000005  
rcx=0000000000000006  
rcx=0000000000000007    
rcx=0000000000000008  
rcx=0000000000000009 
rcx=000000000000000a 
rcx=000000000000000b  
rcx=000000000000000c  
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x14:  
00007ffe`6ccdd424 c3              ret
```

now see for the same conditional with gc

```
cdb -c "bp foo!b \"r rcx;gc\";g main;pc;p" foo.exe |awk "/Reading/,/quit/"    
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'bp foo!b "r rcx;gc";g main;pc;p'  
rcx=0000000000000003
foo!b:
00000001`40001030 894c2408        mov     dword ptr [rsp+8],ecx ss:00000000`0014feb0=00000000
p
0:000> foo!b+0x4:
00000001`40001034 4883ec38        sub     rsp,38h
p
0:000> foo!b+0x8:
00000001`40001038 c744242007000000 mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h],7 ss:00000000`0014fe90=00000000
bl
0:000>  0 e 00000001`40001030     0001 (0001)  0:**** foo!b "r rcx;gc"
```

Comment: Thanks, another nugget to add... as usual ;)